# Animate newly created View of unknown size

Tags: android, android-animation, android-custom-view

I want to animate View right after it was added to parent (something like DrawerLayout). The problem is that View has varying size, and animation target position depends on that size. Simplified sample code:

```
    AnimatingView extends View {
        public int offsetX;

        @Override
        protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
            final int screenWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
            final int screenHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
            offsetX = calculateOffset(screenWidth);
            ...
        }
    }
```

Code similar to this triggers the animation:

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        AnimatingView animatingView = new AnimatingView(getContext());
        parentLayout.addView(animatingView);
        animatingView.animate().x(animatingView.offsetX).setDuration(500).start();
    }
```

In this case `onMeasure()` happens after `animate()`, so animation fails. What is the correct way of doing stuff which depends on view measuring?

The simple & stupid way would be something like `animateOnceAfterMeasuring()` based on `isInitialized` flag, but I don't think it the correct way of doing this.

Comment: Why dont u use `android:animateLayoutChanges' attribute in your parent layout xml

Comment: put `animatingView.animate().x(animatingView.offsetX).setDuration(500).start();` line inside `parentLayout.post(new Runnable() {});`

Comment: @sohanshetty In that case parent ViewGroup will layout the child in default position, not in the position where child should actually stop it's movement

Comment: @AkshayBhat'AB' `post()` has no guarantee to be run after layout cycle

Comment: what post does is it will add the runnable to the message queue. So the operations you do before will already be in message queue, so it will execute only after layout/drawing pass.

Answer (score 2):

this should work:

```
    AnimatingView animatingView = new AnimatingView(getContext());
    parentLayout.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
                v.removeOnLayoutChangeListener(this);
                animatingView.animate().x(animatingView.offsetX).setDuration(500).start();
            }
         });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ViewTreeObserver for this

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    final AnimatingView animatingView = new AnimatingView(getContext());
    parentLayout.addView(animatingView);
    animatingView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
                animatingView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutL‌​istener(this);
            } else {
                animatingView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutList‌​ener(this);
            }
            animatingView.animate().x(animatingView.offsetX).setDuration(500).start();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: you should remove this listener after global layout:

`if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
   animatingView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);

} else {

animatingView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);

}`